# Graph shortest path .. use only labelled edges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, graph-algorithm, sql-server-2019

With the new SQL Server version there is the function `SHORTEST_PATH`.
I use attributes (or Labels) in the edge tables to distinguish the different types of connections.

Unfortunately the `SHORTEST_PATH` function doesn't seem to allow any attributes in the where condition (if the tables are marked for path)

```
SELECT
       l1.CommonName AS CommonName, 
       STRING_AGG(l2.CommonName, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS Verbindung,
       LAST_VALUE(l2.CommonName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS LastNode
 from           object as l1, 
                connections for path as v,
                object for path as  l2 
    where match(SHORTEST_PATH( l1  (-(v)-> l2)+))
    and l1.CommonName = 'jagdtWurst'
    and v.label= 'hierarchie' <<--- This is not possible .... Error
```

Is there a no trick to how to do that anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can use a subquery in the `from` clause.  eg

```
SELECT
       l1.CommonName AS CommonName, 
       STRING_AGG(l2.CommonName, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS Verbindung,
       LAST_VALUE(l2.CommonName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS LastNode
 from           object as l1, 
                (select * from connections where label = 'hierarchie') for path as v,
                object for path as  l2 
    where match(SHORTEST_PATH( l1  (-(v)-> l2)+))
    and l1.CommonName = 'jagdtWurst'
```

Comment: Thank you. You made my day.